# How do I make segments (of my probabilities?)

Tags: r, probability, segment, identification

I was wondering if there is a function which can help me with segmentation. Via mixtools (logisregmixEM), I got an optimum of 3 segments with corresponding size of 2.5%, 40.3% and 57.2%. I also got posterior probabilities. Is there any way how to create three separate segments with corresponding observations based on the probabilities, in which I end up with 3 segments with the above called sizes?

For what its worth some background information of my coefficients, and probabilities:

```
> dput(head(betas))
structure(list(comp1 = c(4.57, 0.08, 0.91, -0.11, 0.09, 0.07), 
comp2 = c(2.04, -0.22, 0.19, 0.34, -0.34, -0.01), comp3 = c(0.88, 
0.03, 0.42, -0.02, -0.17, -0.01)), row.names = c("beta.0", 
"beta.1", "beta.2", "beta.3", "beta.4", "beta.5"), class = "data.frame")


> dput(head(posteriorp))
structure(c(0.06, 0.03, 0, 0.03, 0, 0, 0.61, 0.42, 0.07, 0.41, 
0.31, 0.41, 0.33, 0.56, 0.93, 0.56, 0.69, 0.59), .Dim = c(6L, 
3L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, c("comp.1", "comp.2", "comp.3")))
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by segments. What's the output you want?

Comment: I want to describe my segments better. As for example. The beta of being male in segment 1, 2 and 3 are respectively 0.91, 0.19 and 0.42. So: more churning (= dependent variable) in segment 1 if being a male, compared to the other segments. But what I really want to is to describe each of the segments. So for example how to characterize/describe the segments @camille

Comment: Still too broad. What code do you have so far and what exactly is the output you want?

Comment: I apply finite mixture modeling. The dependent variable is binary. Several predictors are tested on this dependent variable, which gave me the output (in coefficients) for each segment. The function logisregmixEM of the package mixtools gave me automatically the output for each segment. What I want is to know how to describe the segments. I thought that maybe I could make subsets, based on the posterior probabilities (idk how) and then for example try to figure out how much male in each segment are tend to churn. That is just an idea, but I don't know how to work stuff like this out.. @camille

Comment: Take a look again at [ask]—this is currently too broad for SO. Questions really need to be about specific code, and right now you have an issue you're looking for theoretical ways to approach. At best, maybe it could be moved to [stats.se] but they might want more specificity as well